# Access does not summarize null values of crosstab query row headings

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, crosstab

I think this should be simple but I have no found a solution so far.
I have a table V_POLE_FR., which has a structure like this (it has more fields)

```
ROWID (integer pk)
PROPRIETAIRE (string)
STATUS_FINAL (string)
```

I would like to summarize the number of poles by PROPRIETAIRE (the crosstab row heading), and get the numbers of each STATUS_FINAL (the crosstab query column heading). I get OK results for all the owners (PROPRIETAIRE) but there are some null values of owner and I get a blank row but with 0 count.
How can I get to sum up also the poles having null owner? I have tried Nz but maybe not doing it right.

Here is my crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Count(V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE) AS [COUNT]
SELECT V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE, Count(V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE) AS TOTAL_PROPRIETAIRE
FROM V_POLE_FR
GROUP BY V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE
PIVOT V_POLE_FR.STATUS_FINAL;
```

And i get results like this (count of zero for nulls which should be 4):

```
PROPRIETAIRE TOTAL_PROPRIETAIRE   <>   A   B   C   D   E
(null)              0              0
X                   1                      1
Y                   81                         75   2
Z                   165                   165
```

The interesting thing is  if I do a simple group by query, I get the totals right but I loose the separation by status:

```
SELECT DISTINCT V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM V_POLE_FR
GROUP BY  V_POLE_FR.PROPRIETAIRE;
```

I thank your help.
By the way I looked at several answers and any seemed to be this case?? I tried the Nz function it did not work.

Comment: You would get more response if you declare your database system and [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Count(1) AS TOTAL_PROPRIETAIRE`
By definition, Count ignores Null values.

Comment: Thanks that did the job!!! I would vote up but no reputation :-). Thanks for everybodys comments and formatting !!!